# Autocad .NET - Get Layer width and height for plotting

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, dwg

i'm struggeling a little with my Autocad Plugin..

Since i have a huge amount of AutoCad Drawings to plot programmatically as a pdf-File i found out that some of them contain much unnecessary stuff on it.

i only want to plot a specific area which is defined in a layer. I have no problem of search for the layer and check for its properties but i can not find a single thing about coordinates or something like a height or a width..

So my question is simple: Is there a chance to get the height and width or something like that to print only the needed stuff inside the area of that layer?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Layers don't have any extents. You need to look at all the objects on that layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a selection set of all the entities you want to plot, loop through and get each entities extents.

Compare each entity against a return value and grab the largest min and max points of everything in your selection set.  This will give your the window area bounds you want to plot.

Comment: i thought tonight over my problem again and i came to the same solution, i will try this and post the result of my try here, thanks!